# Laravel Route::resource

Tags: laravel, rutas

Hay un problema con Laravel, con `Route::resource` que no sé como resolver.

Creo el controlador desde artisan, así:

```
php artisan make:controller PersonaController --model=Persona
```

En routes/web.php tengo

```
Route::resource('personas', 'PersonaController');
```

La lista de rutas me queda así:

```
+--------+-----------+---------------------------+-------------------+-------------------------------------------------+--------------+
| Domain | Method    | URI                       | Name              | Action                                          | Middleware   |
+--------+-----------+---------------------------+-------------------+-------------------------------------------------+--------------+
|        | GET|HEAD  | /                         | entrada           | App\Http\Controllers\MainController@raiz        | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/user                  |                   | Closure                                         | aut:api      |
|        | GET|HEAD  | personas                  | personas.index    | App\Http\Controllers\PersonaController@index    | web          |
|        | POST      | personas                  | personas.store    | App\Http\Controllers\PersonaController@store    | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | personas/create           | personas.create   | App\Http\Controllers\PersonaController@create   | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | personas/{persona}        | personas.show     | App\Http\Controllers\PersonaController@show     | web          |
|        | PUT|PATCH | personas/{persona}        | personas.update   | App\Http\Controllers\PersonaController@update   | web          |
|        | DELETE    | personas/{persona}        | personas.destroy  | App\Http\Controllers\PersonaController@destroy  | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | personas/{persona}/edit   | personas.edit     | App\Http\Controllers\PersonaController@edit     | web          |
+--------+-----------+---------------------------+-------------------+-------------------------------------------------+--------------+
```

El problema aparece con los métodos show y destroy, que tienen la misma URI.

Para el método show (para ver los datos de una persona) he creado (usando el nombre de la ruta), el siguiente enlace:

```
<a href="{{ route('personas.show', ['persona'=>$persona]) }}">
VER
</a>
```

Este funciona perfectamente.

El problema es que para crear el enlace para borrar, lo hago así:

```
<a href="{{ route('personas.destroy', ['persona'=>$persona]) }}">
BORRAR
</a>
```

Pero como la ruta con el nombre "`personas.destroy`" tiene la misma URI que la ruta con el nombre "`personas.show`", en vez de mandarme el método destroy del controlador me manda al método show.

Supongo que, en principio, no debería haber dos métodos con la misma URI pero, ya que los hay, me imagino que deberá haber una solución.
He pensado que, probablemente, el método de borrado debería lanzarse con el método DELETE de HTTP, pero en la documentación no hay nada respecto a como establecer el método HTTP en el helper `route()`.

Vamos, que estaría genial si me dijerais el truco. Después de todo, ya que Laravel ofrece la opción de `Route::resource`, supongo que esto
deberá estar previsto, pero llevo horas buscando en Internet y no encuentro nada.

HELP, PLEASE. SOS.

Comment: si estas trabajando con un versión reciente de Laravel puede dentro de tu formulario, declarar el verbo **HTTP** que será ocupado entonces pudiera quedar así: `@method('DELETE')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hasta donde tengo entendido no se puede hacer simplemente con un link, primero por el hecho de que debes especificar que es metodo delete (lo cual ni siquiera se puede hacer directamente por el metodo de el form si no por una variable extra enviada en el formulario que lee laravel) y segundo por la utilización del csrf, por lo que debes hacerlo ya sea con un formulario utilizando los helpers o con ajax.

ejemplo con formulario :

```
<form action="{{ route('personas.destroy', ['persona'=>$persona]) }}" method="POST">
    @method('DELETE')
    @csrf
</form>
```

con ajax, manteniendo tu estilo de link seria algo así(debes ver como pasar la url de cada link al ajax):

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST', 
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
   data: {
      _method: 'delete',
   },
    success: function(result) {
        // algo de lógica de ser necesaria, como mostrar un success.
    },
});
```

El Ajax lo escribí de memoria, pero debería funcionar.

Ejemplo y explicación en la documentación : https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#form-method-spoofing

Comment: Lo primero, gracias por tu respuesta. Estoy con la versión 5.7 (la más recientita. Lo del ajax no lo había visto en la docu, y quería evitar el formulario, pero no me va a quedar más remedio. Muchas gracias, Reny. Me has abierto mucho la perspectiva, y me has quitado un peso de encima.
Un cordial saludo.

Comment: A la orden, a veces lo mas complicado es saber que buscar, así que comenzando toca leer mucho la documentación y si vez ejemplos en linea siempre busca que sea lo mas actual posible, muchas cosas cambian entre versiones.

Lo del Ajax intenta no huirle mucho, cuando lo domines mejor podrás ver que con pocas lineas puedes aplicar funcionalidad para todos los botones de eliminar del sistema, porque si te fijas solo cambia la ruta y los datos.

Answer (score 1):

ese no es ningún problema y aunque la URI parezca la misma, los metodos a los que apunta son totalmente diferentes, para persona.show se utiliza GET y para persona.destroy se usa PUT o PATCH, pero como aun no existe esos metodos, laravel te permite hacerlo de forma fácil. De esta Manera puedes incluir el @method = 'DELETE' para eliminar el registro seleccionado y esto debe ir dentro de un formulario con el metodo POST
Ejemplo:

Este te traería el id de $persona lo cual te permitirá ver tod el contenido de dicho registro

```
<a href="{{route('persona.show', $persona)}}" role="button" class="btn btn-info">Ver Registro</a>
```

Por otra parte para Eliminar un registro siempre debe ir dentro de un formulario que apunte al metodo destroy de tu controlador:

```
<f-form accion="{{route("persona.destroy", $persona)}}" metodo='POST>
   @csrf @method('DELETE')
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"> Eliminar </button>
</f-form>
```

Como puedes ver aunque sea la misma URI se usa para fines distintos, la diferencia son sus metodos GET y POST(PUT o PATCH). Saludos +503.